# how to run java database program to another machine?

Tags: java

i have done one java project that using the jdbc to connect with my localhost server (ms server). I don't know how can i connect my localhost database to another machine to run this project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Database is not accessible to the internet and the other machines are not on the same network, then you will not be able to connect to it. In both cases you need to configure your host machine to allow connections to the specific port you are using for the database. You also need to know your IP of the host machine.

For example: If you are using MySQL as your DB, it defaults to port 3306. You would need to configure rules for both your local network firewall to allow incoming/outgoing connections on that port (or another port that you then forward to 3306), **and also** configure your host machine to allow incoming/outgoing connection.

The safest way to do this would be to establish an SSH connection, otherwise you are just opening yourself up for all kinds of attacks from the web.

**In your code:** You will have to point your JDBC connector to the IP address and port of the server you are trying to connect to.

For example:

```
private final String server   = "jdbc:mysql://<HOST IP>:3306/<DB TABLE>";
private final String userName = "<USERNAME>";
private final String passwd   = "<PASSWORD>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information for a better anwer :)

Depending on your need, you either need to make your machine & DB accessible from another machine, or every machine will need its own database.

You may also want to separate Server and Client side, where the Server app will be deployed on your machine, have access to the DB and do the logic, and the other machines will only need the Client app that will contact your Server (you'll still need to make your machine accessible).